# What is the growth rate of OEIS A347913?

Tags: exponential-function, multisets, oeis

OEIS [A347913](https://oeis.org/A347913) is an extremely interesting sequence about multisets of integers. It is defined as the number of multisets one can get starting with a multiset of $n$ zeros and "splitting", that is, increasing one number with a duplicate by 1 and decreasing the duplicate by 1. What is the limiting ratio of two consecutive terms of this sequence, if it exists? If it doesn't exist, what is the limit of the nth root of the nth term? The post has a lower bound  of $2$, and I have managed to upper-bound it by $4$ using a clever injection to [A000571](https://oeis.org/A000571).

Here's an example to show A347913(4):

{{$0,0,0,0$}}

{{$-1,0,0,1$}}

{{$-1,-1,1,1$}}

{{$-1,-1,0,2$}}

{{$-2,0,1,1$}}

{{$-2,0,0,2$}}

{{$-2,-1,1,2$}}

Comment: It is indeed very interesting. Perhaps your post would be even more so, if you gave the example $a(4)=7$ in extension; personally I first found $6$ and knowing them all written somewhere would have reassured me to tackle a new subject.

Comment: A simple diagram can find all 7, and I verified the first 6 terms by hand using diagrams.

Comment: Here: {{0,0,0,0}}   {{-1,0,0,1}}   {{-1,-1,1,1}}

  {{-1,-1,0,2}}  {{-2,0,1,1}}

  {{-2,0,0,2}}   {{-2,-1,1,2}}

Comment: What simple diagram did you use? I've found that using a histogram (counts of every number) seems pretty efficient. One interesting angle I've looked at is the sequences broken up by the number of 0's.

Comment: Based on the OEIS sequence, which extends to $n=25$, the ratio is decreasing for even-numbered terms and increasing for odd-numbered ones; if that continues, then a much narrower range of about $[2.499, 2.525]$ holds.

Comment: That is actually my conjecture on that sequence.